# Estimating the average amount of time that passes when we we read elements element in a loop/iteration

Tags: estimation

I was trying to estimate the amount of time that pass by a program when we read one element from its array (say in python).

Say that I have the times $t_i$ when I traversed a number of elements in the following program:

```
array = [...]
t_i_array = []
while i < n:
  t_start = time.start()
  n_i = random.randint()
  a.readKelements(n_i)
  t_end = time.start()
  t_i = t_end - t_start
  t_i_array.append(t_i)
  i++
```

What is the correct estimate for the average time that passes when we read 1 element? (i.e. time per element, instead of elements per unit time)
Is it:

$$\mu = \frac{\sum^{n}_{i=1} t_i}{\sum^{n}_{i=1} n_i}$$

or is it:

$$\mu = \sum^{n}_{i=1} \frac{t_i}{n_i}$$

Note that $t_i$ is the time to read $n_i$ elements on iteration i.

If they do not estimate the quantity I want, then what is the difference between them?

Why is the following reasoning flawed?

$\frac{t_i}{n_i}$ is the average time to traverse 1 element. Then, why don't we don't this a bunch of times and average those results (what my second equation is doing). Why is that wrong? If you can address that issue at an intuitive level and if possible, at a mathematically rigorous level, that would be optimal.

Answer (score 3):

The usual "average time per element" is total elements on total time.

$\hat\mu = \frac{\sum^{n}_{i=1} t_i}{\sum^{n}_{i=1} n_i}$

The other formula is actually a sum of averages, and doesn't estimate what you want. Consider the case where all the $n_i$ are 1 and compare the two formulas - the first formula gives $∑t_i/n$ (a simple average of individual times) while the second gives $∑t_i$, the total time, exactly $n$ times too large. Now consider a case where the $n_i$ are all 2, the result is again $n$ times too large.

You say in your edit that your second formula is averaging the $t_i/n_i$ ... but it isn't. It merely sums them.

A modified version of the second formula - one where we divide by $n$, *would* average them:

$\hat\mu = \frac{_1}{^n} \sum^{n}_{i=1} \frac{t_i}{n_i}$

- and in that case, would also be an estimate of the average but with different weighting to the ordinary average.

---

If the variance of $t_i$ is proportional to $n_i^\alpha$, then the variance of $t_i/n_i$ is $\propto n_i^{\alpha-2}$, and [an appropriate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean#Dealing_with_variance)* weighted average $\frac{\sum^{n}_{i=1} w_i (t_i/n_i)}{\sum^{n}_{i=1} w_i}$ uses $w_i\propto 1/n_i^{\alpha-2}$.

* optimal in the sense of being minimum variance

When $\alpha=2$ that gives the second formula, and when $\alpha=1$ it gives the first formula.

That is, *either* formula might apply perfectly (or neither of them, at least not perfectly) depending on the situation. Using the "wrong" weighting will still estimate the right thing as long as the $t_i/n_i$ share the same population mean, but less efficiently (possibly, in some cases, much less efficiently).

So the question then becomes, how is the *variance* of $t_i$ related to $n_i$? Does it increase linearly in $n_i$, or as the square?

Comment: Sorry I don't see the problem. Do you mind explaining in more detail what the problem was with the second one?

Comment: If you do as I ask and consider the formulas when all the $n_i$ are 1, the first formula gives $\sum t_i/n$ (a simple average of individual times) while the second gives $\sum t_i$, the total time, exactly $n$ times too large. Why *doesn't* that strike you as a problem?

Comment: I did do it and it was strange, but that doesn't explain me or prove to me what the difference between those quantities is. It's odd when $n_i = 1$, but how do I know thats not a special case? (hope I'm not being annoying, I am just trying to genuinely learn)

Comment: The demonstrated fact that it's not giving you an average in the intended sense isn't enough? It was intended to suggest you you how you should modify the formula. Did you consider trying $n_i=2$ for all $i$? Can you see now how to modify the formula to actually give a kind of average?

Comment: The reason that it bugs me is that sure, I know I am wrong, but what bugs me the most is that I don't understand the difference between the two equations and why my intuition was wrong. If I can't fix my intuition, then I am not really learning, I am just memorizing that I am wrong, which I kind of already knew that, I just don't know why the reasoning I wrote on my question is wrong, I just know its wrong. So in that sense, thats why its not enough for me. Though, I appreciate your help, thanks. :)

Comment: I'll try to write an explanation shortly. I thought the example would speak to you, but things aren't always so clear.

Comment: Thanks for your patience and understanding, its greatly appreciated, I will also on my part think more about the example you gave me to see if I gain more understanding. I just rather be honest with me and you, rather than pretended that I understand something that I don't.

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: And updated again. Having dealt with your misunderstanding (that you still thought your sum was an average), I have now explained how to choose between the first average and the correct average for the second formula.